# jQuery Validation Engine and hashing with Sha512

Tags: jquery, sha512, jquery-validation-engine

I have a problem with getting the password hashing working alongside with jQuery validation engine. The problem is that I can't seem to hash the given password.

This is what i have so far.

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery("#form").validationEngine('attach', 
    {onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
        if (status == true) {
             $("form#form").bind('submit', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
             });

             function formhash(form, password) {
               var p = document.createElement("input");
               form.appendChild(p);
               p.name = "p";
               p.type = "hidden";
               p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
               password.value = "";
               form.submit();
              }
         }
     }  
    })
    };
    </script>
```

By running the processing script after the submission I can find and use the un-hashed password but that just isn't good enough for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I applied some more javascript and an additional "background validation" by isolation the function (formhash) and put in in a seperate file, added onsubmit="return validate(this);" in the form header. It ain't that pretty but it seems to do the trick.

Any suggestions about improvments are still welcome though.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function validate(form) {
    var reason = "";

    reason += validatePassword(form.password);

    if (reason != "") {
    return false;
    }
    formhash(form, form.password)
    return true;
    }

    function validatePassword(fld) {
    var error = "";

    if (fld.value == "") {
       error = "";
    }
    return error;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: do you ever execute `formhash(..,..) ` somewhere?

Comment: I tried to call it in the form header with an onsubmit. That resulted in the form submitting even when validation failed.

Comment: but when you calculate the hash and erase the original password in this function, which you never call.. how do you expect the password to disappear?

Comment: Honestly i'm not that familiar with JavaScript nor jQuery. I'm not sure that i understand your question though but if i'm not mistaken the way i see it is that it takes the password, hashes it and then sends the hashed data to avoid any snatching on the way during transaction. When to use it again, re-hash it to be able to compare it to the stored password.

Comment: Improvement to form-validation with javascript would be form validation in HTML5

Comment: How safe are they to use nowadayes considering browser support etc?

Comment: if you consider safety, you have to check form validity on the server-side too!!
However, html5 forms are supported in the newest versions of chrome and firefox. But there are solutions like modernizr.js that gives all browsers those capabilities via js, have a look:
http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/

Comment: Yes, ofcourse i validate the data server-side aswell. Thank you for the information and thanks for your time people.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but I had the same question and found no answer, so I would like to share the way I solved it:

```
function reghash(form, password, confirmation) {
 var p = document.createElement("input");
 form.appendChild(p);
 p.name = "p";
 p.type = "hidden";
 p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
 password.value = "123456";
 confirmation.value = "123456"; }
```

I'm removing the `form.submit();` from this function and calling the function using `onclick` in submit button. I changed the password and confirmation to a safe value by simply matching the min length allowed in jquery form validation. This way the validation function won't prevent submitting the form.